# What are the last common blocks of Bitcoin and its hard forks (Bitcoin Cash, Bitcoin SV etc.)?

Tags: altcoin, blockchain-fork, history

What are the last common blocks of Bitcoin and its most popular hard forks like Bitcoin Cash, Bitcoin SV, Bitcoin Gold, Bitcoin Diamond etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here listed only the top 4 forks by market cap (on 2023-10-12).

| Name | Symbol | Market Cap | Fork Date / Forked From | Last Common Block with Bitcoin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bitcoin | BTC | $523.0bn | N/A | N/A |
| Bitcoin Cash | BCH | $4.2bn | 2017-08-01 / BTC | [478,558](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/block/478558/0000000000000000011865af4122fe3b144e2cbeea86142e8ff2fb4107352d43) |
| Bitcoin SV | BSV | $0.6bn | 2018-11-15 / BCH | [478,558](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/block/478558/0000000000000000011865af4122fe3b144e2cbeea86142e8ff2fb4107352d43) |
| eCash | XEC | $0.5bn | 2020-11-15 / BCH | [478,558](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20cash/block/478558/0000000000000000011865af4122fe3b144e2cbeea86142e8ff2fb4107352d43) |
| Bitcoin Gold | BTG | $0.2bn | 2017-10-24 / BTC | [491,406](https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/block/491406/000000000000000000b23dfce1c518814ec15cc1416f5e72af1844c17d470244) |

Here's an infographic showing their ancestry.

[image]

(infographic credits to Ludovic Lars)